# Angular Cli: -prod build fails on "Abstract class" with Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, abstract-class

I have Abstract class inside app.resolver.service.ts. 
It's working while i'm developing but i have error in PROD build.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

// Annotation section
@Injectable()

abstract class RequestResolver implements Resolve<any> {
      abstract dataUrl: string;
      constructor( public http: HttpClient ){
        this.http = http;
      }
      abstract resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)
    }

    export class ProjectResolver extends RequestResolver {
      dataUrl: string = "https://api.citysdk.waag.org/layers/parking.garage/objects?per_page=50";

      public resolve() {
        return this.http.get(this.dataUrl);
      }
    }
```

[image]

I found working example without abstract class

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

// Annotation section
@Injectable()

export class ProjectResolver {
  private dataUrl: string = "https://api.citysdk.waag.org/layers/parking.garage/objects?per_page=50";

  constructor( public http: HttpClient ){
    this.http = http;
  }

  public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.http.get(this.dataUrl);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using `@Injectable` decorator?

Comment: @yurzui Yes my service has this

Comment: Can you add it to the code?

Comment: You don't need "this.http = http;" when your http parameter is public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular tries to construct the class which has the Injectable() decorator. It cannot be instantiated, because it is an abstract class.